# React Navigation : Keyboard close automatically upon opening with iOS

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tab-view

Since `react-navigation` **6** (while everything worked fine on `react-navigation` **5**), my keyboards no longer work with iOS (it's OK on Android) : they close automatically upon opening.

[image: ezgif-1-cf48b7afd9e1]

I have recreated a very simple example, based on [the official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator#example). This simple example does not work :

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text>Feed!</Text>
  <TextInput style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow', padding: 5, margin: 15}} placeholder="Text input ..." />
</View>
```

- https://snack.expo.dev/FsiQ3p0zo : **not work** on iOS. I am using `react-navigation/material-top-tabs` AND `react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs`.
- https://snack.expo.dev/fydHSeOJi : **work** on iOS : I only use `react-navigation/material-top-tabs`.
- https://snack.expo.dev/ydn-i4P8G : **work** on iOS : I only use `react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs`.

I think this problem occurs when I use `react-navigation/material-top-tabs` and `react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` simultaneously.